# How to add strings in listView (android)?

Tags: android, listview, textview

Lets say we have a listView and two strings. Is it only possible to those two strings by creating a two new TextViews? I guess my real question is, what is the "cleverest" and "best" way to add strings to listView for android.

Code example:

```
private void getEntries(View listView) {
    // Declaring shared preferences variable in order to be able to store data
    final SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES_ENTRY_INFORMATION, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    // Getting information from sp
    final String run = sp.getString(KEY_RUN, "");
    final String litres = sp.getString(KEY_LITRES, "");

    // Adding string data to listView
    listView.add, wait what???

}
```

Comment: You can't add Views or Strings to ListView without using ListAdapter... have a look at this BaseAdapter class developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

ArrayAdapter is good choice IMO.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[]{run, 
litres})
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```